# how to round up to decimal place like money

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I need to round money values up to the nearest cent, then do some operations on that rounded value.  I cannot use Round() because this will also round down.  These are all money values.

123.4567 --> 123.46
1.1349 --> 1.14

Is there any way to do this in SQL?  If I need a UDF, please provide suggestion on how to accomplish code for that UDF.

EDIT: Data is stored as Float.

Comment: What datatype are you using to store these values?

Comment: Not sure, SQL Server 2000, precision doesn't seem to be specified.  Length is 8.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
CEILING(moneyvalue * 100) / 100
```

perhaps? Convert to pennies, round up to nearest whole penny, then convert back to dollars.

Comment: @Jason: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx   Round() will round to nearest within the limit specified. OP wants unconditional round-up.

Comment: Funny, the OP is talking about cents and your answer about pennies and dollars. :)  Obviously off-topic. Just to have a laugh.

Comment: @Marc B, I noticed regarding the value **1.1349**. That's why I removed my comment. Just took me a few minutes to get past the word *round* as this technically isn't a *strict rounding*.

Comment: @Jason McCreary -I learned it in school as "rounding", "rounding-up", and "rounding-down".  There's always many names for techniques.

Comment: @MAW74656, as you'll learn spoken language and technical spec often differ. Most all programming languages *round* `1.1349` to `1.13` by default. Technically speaking, in your case you're double rounding. That is 3 places, then 2 places after the decimal. Which is effectively what **Marc** B has provided.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Ceiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)

```
select ceiling(1.1349 * 100) / 100

result is 1.14
```

Comment: Have you tried running the select I posted? @Downvoter Please comment!

Comment: I downvoted because Ceiling by itself is not useful here.  Your method works as modified, but I had no way to know thats what you meant.  Programming forum, not mind-reading forum.

Comment: How about removing downvote after I updated my answer? Nothing here is written is stone is it?

Comment: -Yes, your right.  Please make an edit to your answer (add a line or something.  Stack is saying I can't change my vote until the question is edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sort of hacky way to get your desired results. Multiply by 100 and take the ceiling - that will round it up the way you want. Then convert it back to money and divide it back down by 100.

```
declare 
    @Value1 decimal(9,4),
    @Value2 decimal(9,4)

select 
    @Value1 = 123.4567,
    @Value2 = 1.1349

select
    @Value1, @Value2

select 
    convert(money, ceiling(@Value1 * 100)) / 100,
    convert(money, ceiling(@Value2 * 100)) / 100
```

Comment: Yes, but Marc B beat you to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code to add precision to it

```
SET @Precision = CAST('1' + (SELECT REPLICATE('0',@Precision)) as int)
SET @Amount= CEILING(@Amount * @Precision) / @Precision
RETURN @Amount
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be great if you could explain your code so it becomes more useful for others.